# T-SQL Select accounts with no activity

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this table

```
ID  InvoiceNo  Created_date
--  ---------  ------------
1   123        1/1/2009
1   234        1/1/2010
1   2304       2/1/2010
1   av245      3/1/2011
1   45wd3      4/1/2011
2   345        1/1/2010
2   4w5        2/1/2010
```

I am trying to select the ID where there has been no activity since 11/1/2010. 
so my results should only show ID 2.

I used EXISTS, NOT EXIST but it still shows ID 1. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is a mismatch between your sample data and your expectation. " my results should only show ID 2." But you have ID 1 with an InvoiceNo 45wd3 that was created on 4/1/2011, which is more recent that 11/1/2010. You probably missed the 10/11 difference in the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not optimized for performance, but I would just do something like this:
*quick and dirty alert*

```
select distinct q.id from (select id, max(created_date) as latestdate from TABLENAME group by id) q where q.latestdate <= '2010-11-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

in oracle i might write something like this:

```
select id from mytable
MINUS
SELECT id from mytable where created_dt > '2010-11-01'
```

to use NOT IN:

```
select * from mytable 
where id not in ( select id from mytable where created_dt > '2010-11-01' )
```